# Building's server room is unlocked: What danger is my building in?

Tags: hardware, physical

In one of the buildings I work in, there are lawyers and accountants, web developers and marketers, and numerous other small businesses. Everyone's (shared) internet is routed through the same server room (which doubles as a broom closet), which is left unlocked and could be accessed by the public during working hours.

This seems to me to be a ridiculous security risk, but I don't know exactly how to quantify that to the building owner and/or the businesses at risk.

Exactly what sorts of risks are we facing and what danger are we in?

Answer (score 11):

1. I can just walk in, plug something similar to [this](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/collections/gadgets/products/throwing-star-lan-tap-pro) into your
   network and read the unencrypted network traffic of the entire
   building.
2. I can snip a few cables and cause a denial-of-service for multiple businesses. This will be pretty hard to diagnose if the building does not have a network admin on hand to deal with such issues.
3. I can steal all the networking equipment.

There is a whole bunch of things I can think of but it would be pointless to list them all. Locking the server room isn't that difficult..

Comment: The first thing there is what I was thinking most of. Law firms and accounting offices are sharing lots of private stuff.

Comment: "Steal all the networking equipment" is a good reason to tell the building owner if they also own the server equipment. :)

Answer (score 0):

All of Terry Chia's points are exactly the concerns.  On how to quantify the risk to your management; you could try to convince your management to hire a pentester.  I'm surprised that the legal folk don't have a problem with leaving a port hole to their sensitive legal data open.